# Stepping away from loops

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, nested-loops

Im counting down how many Sunday 1st are there in the year interval lets say
2000/1/1 and 2020/5/2

I have made function for that which works fine , but the problem is i have nested loops inside which makes it quite slow .

```
int sundaycount = 0;
for (i = year1; i<year2; i++) { // years
    for (j = 0; j<12; j++) {
        if (isdate(i, j, 1)) {
            sundaycount++;
        }
    }
}
```

- ofc there are conditions inside loops for right working , how could i step away from nested loops and make the iteration/code faster?

Comment: Can you quantify "quite slow"? What does `isdate()` do?

Comment: I suspect the bigger problem would be `isdate()`.

Comment: sorry , to explain , im using doomsday alghoritm to calculate anchorsday / doomsday and check what day is the day passed as arguments to the isdate() function, also as  i said this isnt whole loop , is omited the conditions for when the date start at 5 month and ends at 6 month and so on. I can update question with conditions if needed.

Comment: N.B. I think this can also be computed in closed-form. [My mental algorithm](http://pastebin.com/eGWj0TNK) for a related task, coded in Python, may be useful.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and quantify "quite slow".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post the code for `isdate()`.  We cannot verify your problem. I cannot believe 240 calls to `mkdate()` can qualify as *slow*.

If you really want to use less computing power, compute the weekday for the 1st of January of the first year and iterate on the range of years, testing each month by adding the number of days modulo 7.  Just be careful with leap years.  This might consume a bit less CPU, but I doubt you can measure that.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Olaf: That's debatable.  I did give as much of an answer this question can get.  The OP can use my suggestion to try and make his code faster.